# What is the proper way to notate the end of a section played "sul ponticello"?

Tags: technique, notation, strings, violin, viola

That is, what is the standard way to tell a string player to play normally again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **ordinario** or **normale**:

> **ordinario or normale**: to bow in the ordinary or normal fashion, canceling a previous instruction to play s.p. or s.t.
>   abbreviations: ord. ; norm.; N.  - [source](http://www.moderncellotechniques.com/bow-techniques/ponticello-tasto/ponticello-tasto-overview/)

Answer (score 4):

'loco' is also used in these situations.